# Not seeing my builds in itunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, xcode9

I am trying to update my app to the app store. I am able to successfully build it (I see the green check mark that says "submission successful") but I do not see the plus button to add my build online. Any help with recognizing where my issue could be located would be super appreciated, thank you!

I do not see the plus button on this image. Instead it asks me to use Xcode to upload. However, I already did!
[image: asks for plus button]

Despite that, I do not see my upload in the build activity section. You can see that none are from recent dates or have the build number 32.
[image: No build listed]

Here are the build settings I selected. I selected distribution.
[image: my settings]

This led to the following error so  I switched back to the defaults.
[image]

I have tried to upload through a different method which is the Application Loader but it tells me that the binary is already uploaded. Does that mean I should see it in itunesConnect? Why could it not be appearing? Could someone kindly explain what the path specified in this message is referring to?
[image: This message tells me that there is already a binary somewhere. But where?]

For sanity, this is the screen from ApplicationLoader confirming that is is uploading to my app.
[image: Showing that I selected correct app.]

*What have you tried so far?*

- I searched for similar questions on StackOverflow and then followed
  the suggestions for similar problems.
- Apple has not sent me an email with any problems detected in the build.
- I have changed the build number to a brand new number (32).
- I have waited several days.

Comment: In Activity section, You can see it may be pending. it take 1-2 H change pending status,

Comment: Just submit a new build and use Automatic Signing. Don't forget to increment the version or the build #.

Comment: @zDoctor! please check your activity tab and check your build is processing or not? Also check your email properly. There might be some email from itunes connect which have issue.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif At this time the activity tab shows no processing builds and I have received no email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this before, usually waiting fixes the issue (I've had to wait up to a day). Processing might take a while. One time, it didn't fix the issue.

You clearly stated that you waited 2 days, which I also did, and all I could do was contact the Apple support. They fixed it quite fast (I think I got lucky they answered fast also). Basically it was an issue on their end, they answered something like "all your pending builds should now be visible in your itunes connect account". I could then see like 6 versions ready to publish.

So yeah, you've seen to have done your homework, and a pretty decent job a it. Ask for help on their end, maybe copy them your question for more detail.

Comment: Ultimately I needed to contact them and learn that, while my app build had not succeeded, they were not able to get that information to me. So if someone is reading this I would advise you call them. Finding their number was very difficult so I will save you a step:  
+1 (800) 633-2152